# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Cap%C3%ADtol%2014/informacion.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I'm new in using xampp and AJAX. My error is in the console of my browser when I click a button and is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Cap%C3%ADtol%2014/informacion.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, isolated-app, brave, https, chrome-untrusted, data, chrome-extension, chrome.
```

My code HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Història de Cofla 14</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="getInfo">Obtenir informació</button>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my JS is

```js
const getInfo = async () => {
  resultado = await axios("informacion.txt");
  resultado = resultado.data;
  console.log(resultado);
};

document.getElementById("getInfo").addEventListener("click", getInfo);
```

Finally, the "informacion.txt" is a document in teh same folder which is

```
{
    "aprobados": 1456,
    "desaprobados": 24
}
```

And my xampp panel control have the modules Apache and MySQL in "Start"

Anyone knows how can solve the error so makes the page http instead of file?

Comment: Your code needs to run from the server. Looks like you are running it from the file system (e.g. `file://`). Start your server and navigate to it's url, usually localhost or a port on localhost. Your server should tell you where.

Comment: Yes, I supposed that was the error but I don't know how to run from the server and convert my file:// to an http:// or similar

Comment: Literally type `localhost` in your browser's address bar. See what happens. If a page loads, your server has started. If it does not, goto your xampp control panel, and click the start button for Apache. Also check the port number used. You may need to type it on the url, e.g. `localhost:8080` where replace the number with the actual port.

Comment: Also bear in mind that if your `htdocs` folder contains scripts that go to a control panel of some kind, then `localhost` will load that instead of what your stuff. To get around that, either (1) move those scripts to a different folder, (2) change the httpd.conf file to point to a different folder, or (3) *** best option, put your project in a subfolder under htdocs, then navigate to that in your browser, e.g. `localhost/myproject/`.